# bash script does not work

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a bash script that does the following:

> The following bash script will populate Keystone with some initial data:
>
> - Projects: admin and services
> - Roles: admin, Member
> - Users: admin, demo, nova, glance, quantum, and cinder
> - Services: compute, volume, image, identity, ec2, and network

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Modify these variables as needed
ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD:-password}
SERVICE_PASSWORD=${SERVICE_PASSWORD:-$ADMIN_PASSWORD}
DEMO_PASSWORD=${DEMO_PASSWORD:-$ADMIN_PASSWORD}
export OS_SERVICE_TOKEN="password"
export OS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:35357/v2.0"
SERVICE_TENANT_NAME=${SERVICE_TENANT_NAME:-service}
#
MYSQL_USER=keystone
MYSQL_DATABASE=keystone
MYSQL_HOST=localhost
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
#
KEYSTONE_REGION=RegionOne
KEYSTONE_HOST=10.10.10.10

# Shortcut function to get a newly generated ID
function get_field() {
    while read data; do
        if [ "$1" -lt 0 ]; then
            field="(\$(NF$1))"
        else
            field="\$$(($1 + 1))"
        fi
        echo "$data" | awk -F'[ \t]*\\|[ \t]*' "{print $field}"
    done
}

# Tenants
ADMIN_TENANT=$(keystone tenant-create --name=admin | grep " id " | get_field 2)
DEMO_TENANT=$(keystone tenant-create --name=demo | grep " id " | get_field 2)
SERVICE_TENANT=$(keystone tenant-create --name=$SERVICE_TENANT_NAME | grep " id " | get_field 2)

# Users
ADMIN_USER=$(keystone user-create --name=admin --pass="$ADMIN_PASSWORD" --email=admin@domain.com | grep " id " | get_field 2)
DEMO_USER=$(keystone user-create --name=demo --pass="$DEMO_PASSWORD" --email=demo@domain.com --tenant-id=$DEMO_TENANT | grep " id " | get_field 2)
NOVA_USER=$(keystone user-create --name=nova --pass="$SERVICE_PASSWORD" --tenant-id $SERVICE_TENANT --email=nova@domain.com | grep " id " | get_field 2)
GLANCE_USER=$(keystone user-create --name=glance --pass="$SERVICE_PASSWORD" --tenant-id $SERVICE_TENANT --email=glance@domain.com | grep " id " | get_field 2)
QUANTUM_USER=$(keystone user-create --name=quantum --pass="$SERVICE_PASSWORD" --tenant-id $SERVICE_TENANT --email=quantum@domain.com | grep " id " | get_field 2)
CINDER_USER=$(keystone user-create --name=cinder --pass="$SERVICE_PASSWORD" --tenant-id $SERVICE_TENANT --email=cinder@domain.com | grep " id " | get_field 2)

# Roles
ADMIN_ROLE=$(keystone role-create --name=admin | grep " id " | get_field 2)
MEMBER_ROLE=$(keystone role-create --name=Member | grep " id " | get_field 2)

# Add Roles to Users in Tenants
keystone user-role-add --user-id $ADMIN_USER --role-id $ADMIN_ROLE --tenant-id $ADMIN_TENANT
keystone user-role-add --tenant-id $SERVICE_TENANT --user-id $NOVA_USER --role-id $ADMIN_ROLE
keystone user-role-add --tenant-id $SERVICE_TENANT --user-id $GLANCE_USER --role-id $ADMIN_ROLE
keystone user-role-add --tenant-id $SERVICE_TENANT --user-id $QUANTUM_USER --role-id $ADMIN_ROLE
keystone user-role-add --tenant-id $SERVICE_TENANT --user-id $CINDER_USER --role-id $ADMIN_ROLE
keystone user-role-add --tenant-id $DEMO_TENANT --user-id $DEMO_USER --role-id $MEMBER_ROLE

# Create services
COMPUTE_SERVICE=$(keystone service-create --name nova --type compute --description 'OpenStack Compute Service' | grep " id " | get_field 2)
VOLUME_SERVICE=$(keystone service-create --name cinder --type volume --description 'OpenStack Volume Service' | grep " id " | get_field 2)
IMAGE_SERVICE=$(keystone service-create --name glance --type image --description 'OpenStack Image Service' | grep " id " | get_field 2)
IDENTITY_SERVICE=$(keystone service-create --name keystone --type identity --description 'OpenStack Identity' | grep " id " | get_field 2)
EC2_SERVICE=$(keystone service-create --name ec2 --type ec2 --description 'OpenStack EC2 service' | grep " id " | get_field 2)
NETWORK_SERVICE=$(keystone service-create --name quantum --type network --description 'OpenStack Networking service' | grep " id " | get_field 2)

# Create endpoints
keystone endpoint-create --region $KEYSTONE_REGION --service-id $COMPUTE_SERVICE --publicurl 'http://'"$KEYSTONE_HOST"':8774/v2/$(tenant_id)s' --adminurl 'http://'"$KEYSTONE_HOST"':8774/v2/$(tenant_id)s' --internalurl 'http://'"$KEYSTONE_HOST"':8774/v2/$(tenant_id)s'
keystone endpoint-create --region $KEYSTONE_REGION --service-id $VOLUME_SERVICE --publicurl 'http://'"$KEYSTONE_HOST"':8776/v1/$(tenant_id)s' --adminurl 'http://'"$KEYSTONE_HOST"':8776/v1/$(tenant_id)s' --internalurl 'http://'"$KEYSTONE_HOST"':8776/v1/$(tenant_id)s'
keystone endpoint-create --region $KEYSTONE_REGION --service-id $IMAGE_SERVICE --publicurl 'http://'"$KEYSTONE_HOST"':9292/v2' --adminurl 'http://'"$KEYSTONE_HOST"':9292/v2' --internalurl 'http://'"$KEYSTONE_HOST"':9292/v2'
keystone endpoint-create --region $KEYSTONE_REGION --service-id $IDENTITY_SERVICE --publicurl 'http://'"$KEYSTONE_HOST"':5000/v2.0' --adminurl 'http://'"$KEYSTONE_HOST"':35357/v2.0' --internalurl 'http://'"$KEYSTONE_HOST"':5000/v2.0'
keystone endpoint-create --region $KEYSTONE_REGION --service-id $EC2_SERVICE --publicurl 'http://'"$KEYSTONE_HOST"':8773/services/Cloud' --adminurl 'http://'"$KEYSTONE_HOST"':8773/services/Admin' --internalurl 'http://'"$KEYSTONE_HOST"':8773/services/Cloud'
keystone endpoint-create --region $KEYSTONE_REGION --service-id $NETWORK_SERVICE --publicurl 'http://'"$KEYSTONE_HOST"':9696/' --adminurl 'http://'"$KEYSTONE_HOST"':9696/' --internalurl 'http://'"$KEYSTONE_HOST"':9696/'
```

But as I execute it, I get various errors. Please guide me.

Comment: What are the errors you are getting? Did you copy/get this script from somewhere on the internet? If yes, I'm 90% certain that you need to edit the variables to suit your environment.

Comment: im taking guidence from this website:       http://docs.openstack.org/grizzly/basic-install/apt/content/basic-install_controller.html

Comment: here you can see on the "openstack identity service" column,this whole bash is written.i just copied and execute it.but as i do it,i get various errors starting to appear on my terminal.

Comment: ive done everything very carefully ,in other words everything was going fine untill i got stuck on this script.i cant move forward with my work on deploying openstack.please guide me and give me the safest solutions without any errors.it would be very kind of you...

Comment: Okay, I don't really know what OpenStack or Keystone is, but I'll try to understand what is happening. Did you follow all the steps in that link? Did you change anything while following those steps, like IPs, names, passwords? Edit your question to include the errors that you get from the terminal.

Comment: yes i did follow all the steps accordingly, as what is written on that website...like i said i just got stuck here.and NO i didnt change anything.i did allow a automatic IP because in the script they gave it a manual,its a minor thing,it doesnt create any problem because its upto the user,he can give a manual or dhcp automatic whatever he feels like..

Comment: and sorry Alaa i cant copy the errors and paste them here,ive tried to paste those errors here quite a few times but no luck.i cant copy them from my terminal nor i know how to

Comment: but still ill google it and try to paste them here

Comment: I think you'll need to edit this part in the script: `KEYSTONE_HOST=10.10.10.10` and change the IP to whatever IP you gave your host. I also think that it would be wiser to post your problems under the "comments" section in that website.

Comment: i did change my IP address and ok ill ask them aswell

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. I believe you are trying to run the script using

```
sh keystone.sh
```

Try this, first set execute privilege on the script

```
chmod +x keystone.sh

./ksystone.sh
```

This works for me.